# Car sometimes starts rough, almost stalls when coming to a stop, poor fuel mileage

Tags: starting, fuel-consumption, chrysler, 200

I have a 2013 Chrysler 200 LX 2.4L 4speed automatic. Last summer it occasionally had difficulty starting. One in every few starts it would start rough. Now I've noticed recently it seems like it's going to stall just before coming to a complete stop. It occasionally starts rough now. The MPG is WAYYY low and I'm getting 16 MPG in the city which is brutal. Wondering if these issues are all related.

thanks

Comment: So, first question : when was it last serviced? You say this problem started last summer, so has it been serviced since and did that make a difference?

Comment: So you continued driving a car that doesn't run right for about a year now? Like @SolarMike says: when was it last serviced? These problems do not somehow magically go away and might indeed cause more issues.

Comment: First thing I would suspect as some kind of vacuum leak.